# Place the div over an image using CSS and responsively?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, nivo-slider

I have a HTML page which is having only the images for entire page and its using the nivo slider for sliding. I need to place the div to make some part of images as click-able one (all the sliding images having the click-able part on same place). The issue is the divs coming below the view port. So I cant able to use the top:some%; to make responsive. When The user reduce the width the nivo slider adjust the height.

But the div not coming in the right place to make clickable.

I tried max-height:100% also.

Do you have any idea how to maintain the div in same place even nivo slider adjusting the height ?

I used the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<div id="wrapperone">
    <div id="wrappertwo">
        <div id="mailcon" class="contnetholder">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="instacon" class="contnetholder">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="twtrcon" class="contnetholder">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="facebookcon" class="contnetholder">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="contentwrapper">

            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/sliderimages/slider1.jpg" data-thumb="images/sliderimages/slider1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/sliderimages/slider2.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/sliderimages/slider3.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt=""  /> 
                    <img src="images/sliderimages/slider4.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" />  
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function isIE () 
  {
        var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
    }
    if (isIE()) {
        if (isIE () < 9) 
            {
                $("#browserbar").show();
            } 
    } 

        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider(
            {   
                effect: 'fade',   
                pauseTime: 20000,
                animSpeed: 2500, 
                directionNav: false, 
                randomStart: true,
                controlNav: false,              
                controlNavThumbs: false,        
                pauseOnHover: false,            
                manualAdvance: false,
            });

        });
</script>
```

THE CSS below

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, input, textarea {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
i {
    font-style: italic;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a, span {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
    display: block;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background: url("../images/bg.png") repeat scroll left top #F2F2F2;
    /*background-color:#000;*/
    color: #3E3E3E;
    font: 12px "Arial",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#browserbar
{
    background-color:#FF9900;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1%;
}
#wrapperone {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrappertwo{
 /* background: url("../images/bodyContent.gif") repeat scroll 50% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden; */
  width: 100%;

}
.contnetholder
{
    border:3px solid #FFF;
    position:absolute;
}

#mailcon
{
    top:795px;
    left:7%;
    width:120px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#instacon
{
    top:854px;
    left:9%;
    width:23px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:20px;
}
#twtrcon
{
    top:854px;
    left:11%;
    width:23px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:20px;
}
#facebookcon
{
    top:854px;
    left:13%;
    width:23px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:20px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1200px){
#mailcon
{
    top:575px;
    left:7%;
    width:90px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#instacon
{
    top:620px;
    left:9%;
    width:17px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:17px;
}
#twtrcon
{
    top:620px;
    left:11%;
    width:17px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:17px;
}
#facebookcon
{
    top:620px;
    left:13%;
    width:17px;
    border-color:red;
    z-index:1005;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:17px;
}
}
```

Comment: resonsively means what?

Comment: There is a map attribute for images... http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: @PratikJoshi even the browser size reduces or the image viewed in mobile the image got reduced it width and height due to nivo slider.But the div I placed maintaining it's same position.I want to place the div also in the same area where the image get reduced width and height.

Comment: @Akxe So we need to calculate co-ordinates when the browser image gets the reduced width and height ..am I right....If I am right...is there any plugins for that ??

Comment: Can you share a link to a working/testing version?

Comment: @Shina http://tn72.com I have email, and social networking link... But when the browser get resized the div wont be moved. I want to make the div clickable even the window get resized...

Comment: @svk Yes you are. I don't know any plugins... You might have to do this on your own

Comment: Would this plugin (responsive image map) do the trick? http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html